# CSS - How to make parent div responsive?

Tags: html, css, parent

I have a child div inside a parent div in order to make the child div responsive. I would like to make the parent div responsive as well, but after days of searching I haven't found any solutions.

My Code:

CSS

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #b5b5b5;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.css-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1050px;
    height: 345px;
    margin: 3.5em auto auto auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
.css-slideshow div {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
}
.css-slideshow img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="css-slideshow">
        <div>
            <img src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nupebzh4/2/).

The grey portion is the parent div that I would like to be responsive so that it's bottom aligns with the bottom of child div (css-slideshow) as resolution decreases. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I would like the parent div's height to be responsive, not it's width, which is set to 100% in order to make it stretch across the entire page.

NOTE: The space above the image (child div: css-slideshow) is intentional; it makes room for a navigation bar. The z-index in css-slideshow is to keep it behind a responsive dropdown menu.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4):

If you get rid of the position: absolute on the child and the height on the parent it appears to work. Is there a reason you made it position absolute?
http://jsfiddle.net/nupebzh4/4/

When you made the child position: absolute, it took it out of the dom flow. This made it so the parent did not know how tall the content was, which is why you had to hardcode a height. If you put the child back in the flow the parent container can auto size itself to contain the content as it changes size since you don't need to hardcode a height.

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #b5b5b5;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.css-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 3.5em auto auto auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
.css-slideshow div {
    margin: 0;
    max-width:100% !important;
    /* responsive */
    height:auto;
}
.css-slideshow img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
    max-width:100% !important;
    /* responsive */
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kevin - not just for a solution but a good explanation of the solution. 

To be honest, I can't remember why I made the parent div absolute. It's been a while since I looked at this code. I think I originally had it within another div, and without the position:absolute it became hidden behind it. I've been working with CSS for a while, but everything I've learned has been through Internet searches and trial and error. I think it's time I learn more about how CSS actually works rather than just search for the code I need.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit your css :

- remove overflow:hidden
- commented the height for .css-slideshow
- remove the height:auto

http://jsfiddle.net/nupebzh4/5/

```
.parent {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        background-color: #b5b5b5;
        position: relative;
        display:inline-block;
     }

.css-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1050px;
    /*height: 345px;*/
    margin: 3.5em auto auto auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.css-slideshow div {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

.css-slideshow img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
    width:100%;
}
```